# best android device for testing app

Tags: android

Lenovo a6000 is not able to run material design code .

Comment: Google Nexus, it is the only one which has pure Android OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a question like this will provoke opinionated, heavily biased answers and provoke flamewar like discussions between religiously fanatic fanboy groups. It is not very wise to ask a question like this.

Furthermore, one single phone is never enough to really get your app tested. It gets you the impression how your app works on one device, but how it will work on all the others, you will never know. You will always need a variety of devices, and I am not just writing about phones, phablets and tablets, but also of different vendors. Because each vendor introduces "his" own peculiarities and quirks and you will notice that while running fine on a Nexus, your app might crash on an HTC or Samsung. Or while running nicely on those, it might not on a Huawei.

Why?

Because.

Because the vendor did *something* the others did not, and no one expected it. But your customers will hold *you* responsible for it. Because *your* app is crashing. And you don't want this.

So bottom line: There is no best phone for testing. Get a number of different devices from different vendors and test on all of them. Yes, it is expensive and tedious work, but you asked for it...and your customers will be thankful for a stable app. :)

Answer (score 0):

Google nexus series is the best. Just use nexus for tests

Comment: `add some references to validate this`